# Can I pick this value for $\delta$?

Tags: limits

Prove 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z^2+c)=z_0^2+c$$

I tried 
$$|z^2+c-(z_0^2+c)|=|z^2-z_0^2|\leq|z|^2+|z_0|^2\leq|z+z_0-z_0|^2+|z_0|^2\leq|z-z_0|^2+2|z_0|^2<\epsilon.$$

Can I pick $\,\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon-2|z_0|^2}\,$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because then $\epsilon-2|z_{0}|^{2}$ may be a negative number.

For a proof, We let $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/(1+2|z_{0}|)\}$, then $|z^{2}+c-(z_{0}^{2}+c)|=|z-z_{0}|\cdot|z+z_{0}|\leq(1+2|z_{0}|)|z-z_{0}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: How did you go from $|z+z_0|$ to $(1+2|z_0|)$?

Comment: $|z+z_{0}|=|z-z_{0}+2z_{0}|\leq|z-z_{0}|+|2z_{0}|=|z-z_{0}|+2|z_{0}|<1+2|z_{0}|$.

Comment: Yes thanks! And why did you choose those values for $\min$? Why $1$?

Comment: You can choose $2$, and then just adjust the other one to be $\epsilon/(2+2|z_{0}|)$ to end with $\epsilon$.